# How to turn an Excel formula into a UDF?

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions, udf

I have a formula to swap last names with first names in cells where the format is "Smith, John".

```
=MID(A4&" "&A4,(FIND(" ",A4)+1),(LEN(A4)-1))
```

I created a function to utilize this functionality and it seemed to work at first. The function is:

`Function SwapNames(text As String) As String
    SwapNames = Mid(text & " " & text, (Find(" ", text) - 1, (Len(text) - 1)) 
End Function`

I converted my workbook to an Add-In filetype so I could use this globally and now it says the Find function is undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Also, I tried converting the Find part into a range, and it only returns "#VALUE"  - - -  `Function SwapLNFN(text As Range) As String
    '=MID(A4&" "&A4,(FIND(" ",A4)+1),(LEN(A4)-1))
    SwapLNFN = Mid(text & " " & text, Range(text).Find(" ", text) - 1, (Len(text) - 1))
End Function`

Comment: use `WorksheetFunction.Find`.

Comment: you need to use instr, but you could use split() also to achieve maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Nathan_Sav said - use split, and perhaps an optional argument to identify the delimiter.

So `=swapnames("Bartrup-Cook Darren")` returns "Darren Bartrup-Cook" and `=swapnames("Bartrup-Cook Darren","-")` returns "Cook Darren Bartrup"  a `#REF!` error is returned if the delimiter isn't present in the string.

```
Function SwapNames(text As String, Optional Delimiter As String = " ") As Variant

    Dim SplitAt As Long
    Dim NamePart As Variant

    SplitAt = InStr(text, Delimiter)

    If SplitAt = 0 Then
        SwapNames = CVErr(xlErrRef)
    Else
        NamePart = Split(text, Delimiter)

        SwapNames = NamePart(1) & " " & NamePart(0)
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the code, the real work happens with Split(text,Delimiter) which separates the string when it finds the delimiter and puts it into an array. It looks like SplitAt is there for error handling if the delimiter doesn't show up in the string. Is that correct? Also, when does Split() delete the delimiter? When I changed `Delimiter As String = " "` to have a comma as the delimiter, the comma gets deleted. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, `SplitAt` is just to check the delimiter exists within the text before attempting to split it.  When you use `Split` the text on either side of the delimiter is placed into separate elements of an array and the delimiter is removed.  I've no idea when that actually happens though - it's all part of the same process.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can use [**`Split`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) function and swap the name.

```
Function SwapNames(text As String) As String
    SwapNames = Trim(Split(text, ",")(1)) & " " & Trim(Split(text, ",")(0))
End Function
```

So it will change `Smith, John` to `John Smith` and `Smith, John J` to `John J Smith`.